# SVG - How move img background but mask stay sticky

Tags: html, css, svg, mask

I'm trying to modify this demo

https://tympanus.net/codrops-playground/SaraSoueidan/UHhPmBzJ/editor

I would like to change the position of the image and move it inside the mask but without moving the mask.

"Mask-position" does not respond to what I'm trying to do.

Is there a solution ?

thank you in advance

Comment: @Martijn I don't think they want to move the mask -- they want to move the actual image that shows through the mask.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div containing the image you want to move. To move the image just change the bottom and right attributes.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/LWctq6h3RBOk3Vos?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: Thanks ! Work very well.  It's a perfect solution